# ImageMagick engraving effect on glass

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to add logo on product image with engraving effect.

The original logo is

[image]

After adding it on the product it should look like this.

[image]

how to do this with imagemagick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this as the trophy:

[image]

Then something along these lines:

```
convert trophy.jpg -gravity center \
   \( G.png -colorspace gray -channel a -evaluate multiply 0.2 -resize 120x120 \) -composite result.png
```

[image]

So, I am basically loading the trophy, then in some *"aside processing"* in parentheses, loading the Google logo, converting it to greyscale, reducing the opacity by multiplying it by 0.2, resizing it and compositing it on top of the trophy.

---

By the way, if you were using **GraphicsMagick**, which doesn't have the parentheses I used to make sure I only convert the logo to greyscale and not the trophy, you would do it in a different order. First load the logo and process it (greyscale, resize etc), then load the trophy, then  **swap** the order so the trophy goes to the background, like this:

```
gm convert G.png -colorspace gray -resize ... trophy.jpg -swap -composite result.png
```